# Set Console number of Lines

Tags: command-line, display, screen

The question is about the console you get by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Fx</kbd> (`F2` for instance). Not the `Terminal` from a gnome (...) session.

Whatever the size of the font I choose, the bottom line is always lacking ~2 pixels, thus the cursor is not visible.

I tried to modify `/etc/default/console-setup` and add

```
SCREEN_HEIGHT="800"
```

instead of `"900"` to see if anything changes... but nothing changes.

Is there a way to either

- Change the console number of lines (I'd set the current number - 1)
- Change the screen height to allow for the cursor to be visible

(preferred solution would be the '*number of lines*' one)

---

*Edit*

It's Ubuntu 18.04 on a Macbook pro 15" mid-2015, installed as an alternative boot (using *refind*). `fbset` output

```
mode "2880x1800"
    geometry 2880 1800 2880 1800 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    accel true
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode
```

Comment: What’s the video chip, monitor and cable? Laptop? Run fbset to see the frame buffer info.

Comment: Did you check your monitor settings? Some monitors allow to move the image, thus hiding lines on the edges, or to change the image’s size to adjust it.

Comment: Please see the *edit* part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

`resizecons -lines 40`

This command works with every single one of my Ctrl+Alt+F tty consoles. The number of lines can be set to 25, 28, 30, 34, 36, 40, 44, 50, 60.

if this command is not found you may need to `sudo apt update && sudo apt install console-setup console-setup-linux`

Comment: Great, thanks. The old mode is `288x90` and `resizecons` works. But would be great if the number of lines could be set to 89 (anything above 60 gives *Invalid number of lines*).

Comment: Well, modified the source code (`apt source kbd`, comment out `resizecons.c` line 164) and `src/resizecons -lines 90` works (even if it said it failed) and the cursor appeared! Maybe was lucky, didn't investigate much... (`89` ... work as well)

Comment: @RingØ Wow, thats actually pretty awesome. I didn't actually ever look into increasing the number of lines past 60 (40 rows is my current setting with the selected font because I'm blind as a bat), and for some reason always thought the limit of 60 was hardcoded in some way. Glad it worked out